# Java Arithmetic Operation '--' operator

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to understand the difference between `index = index--;` and `index=--index;` I checked the output of `index = index--;` assignment in the below code block (first example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int index = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        index = index--;
        System.out.println("Index:" + index);
    }//end of for loop
}// end of main method
```

Output:

```
Index:10
Index:10
Index:10
Index:10
Index:10
Index:10
Index:10
Index:10
Index:10
Index:10
```

When I use the `index=--index;` assignment (second example)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            index = --index;
            System.out.println("Index:" + index);
        }
    }// end of main method
```

Output:

```
Index:9
Index:8
Index:7
Index:6
Index:5
Index:4
Index:3
Index:2
Index:1
Index:0
```

I have two questions. In the second example Eclipse throws a warning: assignment `index = --index;`(The assignment to variable index has no effect) But actually it does have an effect on the variable. It decreases its value by 1. Why does Eclipse gives such a warning message?

In the first example, the variable is not affected by the operation (and Eclipse gives no warning). I wonder why Eclipse has no message, and I don't understand why this assignment has no effect over the variable index `index = index--;`

Comment: There is no need to set index = index--; and of which you discovered doesn't achieve anything. The correct practice would be to use just index--; or --index; and the results would be the same. The only difference is how it is evaluated. The index--; wouldn't change the value of index until the next line. --index; would change the value of index at the same line.

Comment: The reason Eclipse is giving you a warning is that `--index` is already changing the value of `index`. You don't need to reassign it to itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `=` and `--` alter the value of `index`. In the case of Java, the `--` is guaranteed to happen before the `=`, so in the case of `index = index--;` the return value of `--` is the old value of `index` and overwrites the decrement of `index` while in the case of `index = --index;` the return value of `--` is already the new value of `index` so the assignment has no effect and `index` stays decremented.

Note that in C the statement `index = index--;` has undefined behaviour and compilers are allowed to decrement index, ignore it or write code that reformats your hard disk (although the latter case is extremely unlikely).

Comment: OK, you mean index=--index; and --index; is the same. But index--; or this index=index--; has no effect on the variable.

Comment: @erhun `index--;` certainly has an effect on the variable! But, it also returns the *old* value of `index`, so that if you write `index = index--;` that immediately undoes the effect of the `--`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is the way assignments are evaluated. When you do `index = index--` the right side of the assignment is evaluated first. Meaning:

1. Return value of `index` on the right side
2. Decrease the value of `index`
3. Set value of `index` to the value on the right side (which is the original value of `index` because it was returned first)

Answer (score 1):

```
index = index--;
```

assigns value first to index on left side and then performs `--` and results will be assigned to any variable (left out in memory).

For example:

```
   index =10;

   index = index--;
```

first assigns value 10 to variable index, it becomes

```
 `10--;`
```

Observe there is no variable pointing to above statement. Now 10-- will results to 9 and left out in memory, but index variable will still point to 10 which is assigned in step1.

Comment: I don't understand... why wouldn't the `10--` then be assigned to index and replace the initial value. If that is the case, why does int v = 10; v = v++; work?

Comment: index = index-1, here you are reducing one from index value and assigning to index. 10-- is not assigned to index.

Comment: I got it now. This link helped too with the PrePostDemo:     http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html. What I wasn't understanding was that with post-fix operations the value isn't changed until the next line.

Answer (score 1):

1) `index--` is a postfix operation. This means, that your assignment `index = index--` will give the previous value of `index` to the same `index` variable. I.e. the `index` value will not be changed.

2) `--index` is a prefix operation. This means, that firstly `index` will be decreased and then it will be assigned to the same `index` variable.

Answer (score 1):

A post-fix operator (`--`) happens after the whatever you're doing.  So:

`index = index--;`

1. Gets the value of index and puts it in a temporary variable (register)
2. Assigns that register value to index
3. Decrements the temporary register (which is then thrown away, because nothing is done with it.)

`index =-- index;`

1. Gets the value of the index and puts it in a temporary register
2. Decrements the register
3. Assigns that register value to the index

Note that these are equivalent:

`index =-- index;`
`index = --index;`

Answer (score 0):

index = index--;

<strike>Translates to:</strike>

```
int temp = index;
index = temp;
temp = temp - 1;
```

Gah, I knew I got it wrong. Correct translation below:

```
int temp = index; 
index = index - 1; 
index = temp;
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1810525/mel-nicholson

Comment: close.  int temp = index; index = index - 1; index = temp;

Comment: Can you show me a source that java do this index=index-- operation   just like your example?